# Инструменты для проверки на кроссбраузерность

Tags: кроссбраузерность

Приветствую!

Вот есть страничка. Она на HTML5, с кучей стилей, конечно CSS3, с какими-нибудь хитроумными конструкциями JS.  И вот мне очень хочется узнать, где она работает, а где нет, и что именно там не работает. Можно накачать кучу браузеров. Можно много чего.

А чем пользуетесь вы для таких целей? Есть ли какие-то инструменты, помогающие отследить проблемы? Что делать с мобильными версиями сайтов?

Comment: http://cleargoalmedia.com/how-to-check-if-a-website-displays-well-across-multiple-browsers-and-operating-systems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я, например, по большей своей части тестирую сайт в Internet Explorer 7 версии. Скажу то, что многие, мягко говоря "ругаются" на этот браузер. Это лишь доказывает то, что верстальщик криворукий и не в состоянии писать грамотный код, т.к IE требует строгих стандартов к себе, а остальные браузеры их опускают. Это и объясняет то, почему все ненавидят IE. Начинайте верстать сайт сразу открывая его в Эксплорере, тогда в любом другом браузере ваш шаблон будет выглядеть идентично. 
Относительно мобильных версий сайта - в основном тестирую под iphone и ipad. iPad у меня есть, а вот айфона нет. Вместо него я эмулирую девайс, устанавливая MAC OS на виртуалку и через xCode просматриваю там свой сайт. Это наилучший вариант тестировать сайты на подобных устройствах, т.к ни один онлайн сервис вам не даст реальных результатов, по причине того, что сайт отображается во фреймах фиксированных размеров.
Также советую погуглить вам тему "адаптивная верстка". Очень полезная штука для моб. устройств, если дружите с английским, то "responsive design". Во втором варианте (во всяком случае для меня нашлось) больше информации.

Comment: Беру статистику посещаемости сайта по данным Google Analytics за 30 дней, а это 17 422 посещения. Из них IE юзают 1 697 а конкретно IE 6 и 7 версии аж 121! В итоге это 0.69% из которых возможно 0.01% сделает заказ!

-----------------

Статистика на столько печальна что я даже рукой не дрогну делать оптимизацию под IE 6 и 7!

Answer (score 0):

Дорогой мой друг , может вы хотите еще такую программу в которую бы загрузили тех задание , а она по нему вам сделала  кросброузерный сайт . 
По по воду того, как сайт выглядит на разных девайсах есть множество сайтов , вот один из них http://quirktools.com/screenfly/
Что касаеться отладки , вам необходимо делать это вручную , и ставить то количество браузеров которое считаете нужным , ведь от этого зависит качество ващей работы. А в один клик сделать не получиться .
Лучший инструмент это: Мозги и намерение , а о стольное придет само мобой

Comment: Ну есть же adobe dreamviwer, device central,... Мне интересно, что есть еще на эту тему? Никто не говорит об одном клике!

Comment: Я использую Sublime Text и плагин Emmet это очень удобно и просто , советую попробовать , в саблайме очень хорошая подсветка синтаксиса , так же поддержка различных плагинов . подключаю скрипт refreshcss которые отслеживает сохраниния в цсс файлах . http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrM1r23bBxs